# rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062} on discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When I run every other command it works perfectly fine, but when I use /rank it shows the "Unknown interaction" error, the error only occurs when the error handeling doesn't have any problems, for example a valid user id and rank id, when it does though, it works perfectly fine.

**I'm not a fan of try{} so if theres a away to fix it with using .try, let me know**

**Code:**

```
if (interaction.commandName === "rank") {
    const tuser = interaction.options.getNumber("targetuser");
    const trank = interaction.options.getNumber("targetrank");

    noblox
      .changeRank(5156922, tuser, trank)
      .then(async () => {
        const username = await noblox.getUsernameFromId(tuser);
        const grn = await noblox.getRankNameInGroup(5156922, tuser);
        interaction.reply(
          `The rank of ${username} has been updated and they have been ranked to **${grn}**`
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.stack);
        interaction.respond({
          content: `Something went wrong, Here is what can have gone wrong: \n\n- **The user id does not exist or isn't in the group**\n- **The rank number does not exist**\nPlease double check the fields. Thank you!`,
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      });
  }
```

Error:

```
rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1193921932316377109/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTE5MzkyMTkzMjMxNjM3NzEwOTpjRkVPQTZlSzUxNE1RQmxzM0M4Y3h1TFN6VU45ZmpkVEtXTXk2cThCalpGUWtiSXZHVnVtVVBxTzR2U01HcDZRb0RRT3RxeXAwYmZxTlpicDZIMjAwb3RreFQ4Wm5CaEN4MXVKdmx1cGZpZGRWdW5YUXo4Q2Zxd3NDZmNOM05WNQ/callback'
}
```

I'm trying to fix the /rank thing, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When responding to a slashcommand you have 3 seconds to send your reply. If you need more time you have defer the reply. You can do this by using `interaction.deferReply()`

Updated code:

```
if (interaction.commandName === "rank") {
    await interaction.deferReply(); // Used await for now, depending on whether you're using async/await or not you'd have to change this
    const tuser = interaction.options.getNumber("targetuser");
    const trank = interaction.options.getNumber("targetrank");

    noblox
        .changeRank(5156922, tuser, trank)
        .then(async () => {
            const username = await noblox.getUsernameFromId(tuser);
            const grn = await noblox.getRankNameInGroup(5156922, tuser);
            interaction.editReply(
                `The rank of ${username} has been updated and they have been ranked to **${grn}**`
            );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error.stack);
            interaction.editReply({
                content: `Something went wrong, Here is what can have gone wrong: \n\n- **The user id does not exist or isn't in the group**\n- **The rank number does not exist**\nPlease double check the fields. Thank you!`,
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Now it's throwing an error: 'InteractionAlreadyReplied'

Comment: @yourmine_broHD Could you show me the rest of your code? Perhaps via a Github link?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yourminebro/Apex-Adventures-Bot/main/index.js

Comment: Ah I see what went wrong. I have updated the code snippet above and it should work now. If you're still getting errors please let me know and I'll try to help you

Comment: Worked, Thank you so, so much for your time!

Comment: @yourmine_broHD If this answer helped you it's useful if you mark it as the answer so that anyone who comes across the post in the future can easily see that it has a solution!